# ASP.NET WebAPI RefreshTokenProvider Expiration Time is Wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

After spending some very good hours on trying to fix this issue, I decided to call for help - maybe someone knows where I'm doing something wrong.

First of all, I'm having an ASP.NET WebAPI (.NET 4.7.2) project configured with BearerAuthentication:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
 TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
 Provider = new CustomerOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
 AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
 RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
 {
   OnCreate = (obj) =>
   {
     obj.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(6);
     obj.SetToken(obj.SerializeTicket());
   },
   OnReceive = (obj) => { obj.DeserializeTicket(obj.Token); }
 },
};
```

Everything works fine, except the refresh token flow; the flow is like this:

1) Issue a short expiration authentication token along with a Refresh token: make a POST request to /token with a username, a password and `grant_type: 'password'`; the response comes back very nice:

```
{
    "access_token": "UN8tE3iJWlIjGX1eTbOEc2nX7qaZ2ACvor...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1799,
    "refresh_token": "fb84E_OqK334Z1t00WrOAm6phYTA63dLye96eE8NF4NV...",
    "userName": "XXXX",
    ".issued": "Sat, 06 Apr 2019 21:14:39 GMT",
    ".expires": "Sat, 06 Apr 2019 21:44:39 GMT"
}
```

2) Exchange the refresh token for a longer authentication token: make a POST request to the same endpoint /token with `'grant_type': 'refresh_token'` and `'refresh_token':'fb84E_OqK334Z1t00WrOAm6phYTA63dLye96eE8NF4NV...'` and surprise - the response that I'm getting back has the same expiration:

```
{
    "access_token": "EwOXPrGOzV9nU_...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1799,
    "refresh_token": "gsPVze9u2auwMZXspFY...",
    "userName": "XXX",
    ".issued": "Sat, 06 Apr 2019 21:20:11 GMT",
    ".expires": "Sat, 06 Apr 2019 21:50:11 GMT"
}
```

I would like to emphasize that I tried also having a custom `AuthenticationTokenProvider` implementation but still no luck.

On doing a bit of debugging (and now I'm speaking also about my custom implementation of AuthenticationTokenProvider), what I observed was that everywhere the expiration time was correct and the the `context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary` always had the correct values except one place (this is from my custom implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`):

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
  {
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
  }

  return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Here the expiration time was the one displayed in the resulted JSON. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

All nuget packages are on the latest version.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting what lifetime are you changing: the `Create` method you provided for your `RefreshTokenProvider` is used for changing properties of the **refresh** token, not the access token. You are setting the expiration time of your refresh token to 6 months.

Comment: Indeed, the refresh token should be valid 6 months and along with that refresh token comes a property called access_token that you use to authenticate calls. Correct?